# newline character in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, newline

How can we get this output

results from query should be like:

```
Assessment 
penalty
```

both values are coming from two different columns. I want to join these two columns but want results like above in single cell. so there should be new line for second column(but in same cell)

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 1):

`select assessment || E'\n' || penalty from wherever`

or

`select concat_ws(chr(10), assessment, penalty) from wherever`

Note: I am assuming, since you didn't say, that neither column can be null.